# VBA create an array which contains formulas

Tags: arrays, vba, range, formula

I would like to know if there a way to create an array which contains only formulas (not value).

for e.g.

```
dim myArr (1) as string
myArr(0) = "=Sum(A1:C3)"
myArr(1) = "=Sum(B1:D3)" 
Range("E1:E2") = myArr
```

The result is cells have above formulas as a string. is there any straightforward method of storing formulas and applying to ranges?.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the array as 2D (because 1D array is a single row for Excel, and you have multiple rows), and you need to declare it as `Variant`.

```
Dim myArr(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As Variant
myArr(1, 1) = "=Sum(A1:C3)"
myArr(2, 1) = "=Sum(B1:D3)"
Range("E1:E2").Formula = myArr
```